# UISearchDisplayController - display table when no text entered instead of overlay

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchdisplaycontroller

When you have no text entered in a UISearchDisplayController's UISearchBar, it displays a semi-transparent overlay over the previous table. I would like to load the table that appears when searching in this scenario to display a list of recent searches. It does appear that searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString: with a blank string when text is cleared, but returning YES still causes that overlay to be displayed, instead of getting table information from my delegate/datasource to display a table. Does anyone have any advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this by creating a whole new table that's added to a subview of the main table in searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:, and then hidden/shown when the search table is shown/hidden (and moved to the front when shown). Not the prettiest solution, but it works.